# Cross browser COMET realization for node.js

Tags: node.js, cross-browser, comet, long-polling

I'm a node.js starter. 
The product I want to deliver looks like online chat with 1000+ participants at a time.
I'm looking for a cross-browser demo (IE7, android support) to start with.

The thing I worry about is **client side** cross browser part. I dream about a library that uses web sockets for supported browsers and iframe for not supported, is well tested, and encapsulates COMET realization.

I have found some solutions in the web, but I'm qurious about your advices.

Thank you

Comment: You're looking for http://socket.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use [socket.io](http://socket.io) which is a quite elaborate tiny library for handling such things. Maybe you want to give it a try as well ;)

Answer (score 1):

I've currently found https://github.com/maccman/juggernaut the best solution. I will come back here in a month and tell about my experience

Comment: Hi @Dan how's your work going? Can you share your exp with us?